# Check that string does not start with any letters from List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, startswith

If I have input a string is it possible to check that the first letter does start with an input from a list of strings:

```
var dir = "FOLDERNAME";
var list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "s", 
                                "t", "u", "v", "w", "z", "y", "z", 
                                "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
if (!dir.ToLower().!StartsWith :MagicLinq: list) { Do Stuff; }
```

Or do I have to go the regex route?

Comment: `var lower = new string(dir?.FirstOrDefault() ?? new char(), 1); if (list.Contains(lower) {` You could simplify that if the list was a list / hashset of `char` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to consider:

```
var lower = new string(dir?.FirstOrDefault() ?? new char(), 1);
if (list.Contains(lower) {
```

The first line gets the first character from the string, and handles empty and `null` strings (by getting the null char), and then loads that `char` into a `string`.

*You could simplify that if the `List<string>` was a `List<char` or `HashSet<char>` instead. Then you could remove the `new string` part.*

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the first letter is in the list:

```
if (list.Contains(""+dir[0])){}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this check will be done many times using a [`HashSet<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) would be more performant than a [linear search](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains#remarks) on a [`List<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1).  Even if performance is not a concern a `HashSet<>` might better represent the data and how its used since each element is unique and ordering doesn't matter.

Here I'm using a `HashSet<>` of `char`s...

```
var dir = "FOLDERNAME";
var restrictedChars = new HashSet<char>(
    new[] {
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G',
        'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'Z', 'Y', 'Z',
        '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
    }
);

if (!restrictedChars.Contains(dir[0]))
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Note that I changed the restricted characters from lowercase to uppercase since [`char.ToUpper()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.char.toupper)/[`char.ToUpperInvariant()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.char.toupperinvariant) are the [recommended way to normalize case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings#chartoupper-and-chartolower) for case-insensitive comparisons.  You could then perform the check in a case-insensitive manner like this...

```
if (!restrictedChars.Contains(char.ToUpperInvariant(dir[0])))
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `HashSet<>` of `string`s and pass in a case-insensitive [`StringComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer) instance...

```
var dir = "FOLDERNAME";
var restrictedChars = new HashSet<string>(
    new[] {
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
        "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "z", "y", "z",
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
    },
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
);

// Get a string from Substring() instead of dir[0].ToString()
if (!restrictedChars.Contains(dir.Substring(0, 1)))
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

With this approach the case of the restricted character `string`s fed into the `HashSet<>` doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i'd do it

```
String dir = "FOLDERNAME";
var MyList = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "s",
                "t", "u", "v", "w", "z", "y", "z",
                "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
Console.WriteLine((MyList.IndexOf(dir.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()) != -1) ? "True" : "False");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Instead of `(MyList.IndexOf(dir.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()) != -1) ? "True" : "False"` why not simply `MyList.Contains(dir.Substring(0, 1).ToLower())`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to c#.  I've never seen the ? used that way.

Comment: If you're referring to the "?" at the end of my comment that wasn't part of the code, just making it a question.  Whether you call `IndexOf(...) != -1` or `Contains(...)` the `?:` ternary operation is not necessary because the prior expression already evaluates to a `bool`, which can be readily converted to `"True"` or `"False"` text by `Console.WriteLine()`.